# Validate a Date format in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a bash script on a cronjob that will be passing a date formatted as so:

```
DATE=`date +"%Y_%m_%d"`
```

My Ruby script then needs to validate whether the date is passed (in this format). If not it uses the current Date. Currently I've some solutions, and I thought this one would work but it doesn't. I'm still having a hard time understanding how Ruby methods work.

```
begin
  Time.parse ARGV[1],"%Y_%m_%d"
rescue
  puts "Invalid Date"
ensure
  $LOG = Time.now
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [`strptime`][1], which accepts a format parameter.

```
Time.strptime "2014_05_09", "%Y_%m_%d"
=> 2014-05-09 00:00:00 -0400
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! this is what I was looking for. Quick question, how do I know what kind of exception a particular method raises in Ruby? I don't seem to see this information in the docs? I come from mostly a C++/python background, and so I am tempted to 'rescue' some exception, but Im not sure what goes there.

Comment: Rubydoc doesn't have this information, unfortunately, but you can test it. In this case, `ArgumentError`.

Comment: If format is not matched it throw `ArgumentError: invalid strptime format - `%Y_%m_%d'`